# Facebook Graph jQuery AJAX call to post a photo on user's behalf

Tags: javascript, ajax, facebook, facebook-graph-api, graph

I'm trying to post a photo on the users behalf. I've been searching the web for the last 4 hours and I'm out of ideas.

**JS:**

```
$.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'https://graph.facebook.com/v2.0/me/photos',
            data: JSON.stringify({
                url: 'https://www.facebook.com/images/fb_icon_325x325.png',
                access_token: token
            }),
            success: function(data){
                console.log(data);
            },
            error: function(a,b,c){
                console.log(a+'|'+b+'|'+c);
            }
        })
```

the error function outputs the following:

> [object Object]|error|Bad Request

I think there must be something wrong with the ajax request itself, but I can't figure out what it is. I've reconstructed my request using the [Facebook Graph API explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer) and everything works fine there. Any ideas?

Comment: The parameter name to pass the user access token is `access_token`, not just `token`.

Comment: You're right, but the same problem remains. But thanks anyway!

Comment: Have you tried passing just the object as `data`, without `JSON.stringify`ing it? (And you don’t want to use the official JS SDK, because …?)

Answer (score 0):

Need to define the correct data type in the ajax request ( jsonp ), just try this will work :

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'https://graph.facebook.com/v2.0/me/photos',
        data: JSON.stringify({
            url: 'https://www.facebook.com/images/fb_icon_325x325.png',
            access_token: token
        }),

        dataType: "jsonp", //Just add this line ( jsonp not json ),

        success: function(data){
            console.log(data);
        },
        error: function(a,b,c){
            console.log(a+'|'+b+'|'+c);
        }
    })
```